# the tableview update it self randomly

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

```
@interface NavigationController : UITableViewController
```

My tableview is created programaticly so no xib file.At the bottom part i update the table when the user click the tab bar. This is why i put it in viewDidAppear. But the table isn't update itself every time, just randomly update.You can see the show value that is written in the table.The nslog writes correct value but the table didn't show the correct value all the time any idea why??

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
[super viewDidAppear:animated];
NSString *country=[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"namecountry"];
//url's
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"someurl"];
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:country forKey:@"c_name"];
[request setRequestMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request startSynchronous];

NSString *response = [request responseString];
NSLog(@"%@",response);
res=[[response componentsSeparatedByString:@","] retain];
NSLog(@"%@",[res objectAtIndex:18]);
show=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[res objectAtIndex:18]] retain];
float f=[show floatValue];
show=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %%",f];
}
```

edit::

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
if (indexPath.row % 2 == 0) {
    // EVEN
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"EvenCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"EvenCell"] autorelease];
        UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
        UIColor *colour = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed: (208.0/255.f) green: (231.0/255.f) 
                                                  blue: (241.0/255.f) alpha: 1.0];
        bg.backgroundColor = colour; 
        cell.backgroundView = bg;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
        [bg release];
        cell.detailTextLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
        show=[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[res objectAtIndex:18]] retain];
        float f=[show floatValue];
        show=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2f %%",f];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text=show;
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

} else {
    // ODD
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"OddCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:@"OddCell"] autorelease];
        UIView *bg = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];

        UIColor *colour = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed: (143.0/255.f) green: (169.0/255.f) 
                                                  blue: (180.0/255.f) alpha: 1.0];
        bg.backgroundColor = colour;
        cell.backgroundView = bg;
        cell.textLabel.backgroundColor = bg.backgroundColor;
        [bg release];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;


} 
return cell;
}
```

Comment: Did you reload the table? What does the table shows?

Comment: i use [self.tableView reloadData]; but it shows same value not updated value but when i close program and start over it shows the right value

Comment: Can you show me the part where you reload the table?

Comment: [self.tableView setDelegate:self];
    [self.tableView setDataSource:self];
    [self.tableView reloadData];

Comment: Check it by reloading the table once, after that NSLog which gives the correct value.

Comment: sometimes it reload but only 1's sometimes not reloading it probably i need to do [self.tableView setDataSource:res]; but it doesnt accept my nsarray res :(

Comment: i did it i write reload after the last nslog

Comment: nop mate still not updateing it :(

Comment: What exactly are you even trying to do? You have empty odd cells and even cells with no normal text, just detail text?

Comment: And every detail text is set to the 19th value of your array?

Comment: Use break point and check whether the scope enters your part of updating the table while reloading. Also check whether it calls the method cellForRowAtIndexPath: when you reload the table.

Comment: yes oddcell is now empty i ll put it later but in evencell i have 2 things textlabel.text this is the name of the country fro example France and the detail one is the percentage %10 something when the user give vote the percentage is going up like %15 but the detailview didnt show the %15 value it still shows %10

Comment: yes the 19 because my database return the correct value at the 19th the others is totaley for different stuff. I only want the detail one shows the correct value .NSlog writes correct value each time just detail don't take it from there

Comment: @Developer i don't even think it reloads

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to show new data in your tableview, you need to call

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

This instructs the tableview to call all the datasource methods and grab the new data. Without making this call, it will continue using cached data.

Comment: i know that but how can i set datasource to my res array?

Comment: What does your `[tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:]` method look like? Add that source to your post?